# Is it okay to include typescript into dependencies (not devDependencies)?

Tags: typescript, heroku

I'm about to push my `NodeJS` app to `Heroku`. It's written in `typescript`, so I basically have two options, as I understand:

1) Move `typescript` dependency to dependencies in my `package.json` <- seems not the best idea to me

2) Push generated `javascript` code and run it on `Heroku` without rebuilding <- also doesn't seem good

Is there any other workaround? If not, which way is preferable?

Comment: Why would you want to run TypeScript compiler on production servers?

Comment: @artem, I don't want, but it seems to me incorrect to have generated code under git. isn't it?

Comment: Don't know about heroku - does it have other ways to deploy code besides taking it from git repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Push generated javascript code and run it on Heroku without rebuilding <- also doesn't seem good

This is the *right* way to do things. You publish and run compiled JavaScript

Comment: Note that instead of pushing generated javascript code to heroku and git repo, you  can build a `dist` folder from `src` folder with remote CLI and run your generated code in `dist` folder. To me it is better approach as it keep your repository cleaner by ignoring `dist` folder.